# Elasticsearch: Pull field from nested child to parent if conditions are met

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

Running Elasticsearch 2.4.4.

I have data that has a default value, then children documents that have time ranges and the highest value overrides the data. Looks like this:

```
{
   "defaultValue": 1,
   "children" : [
      { 
         "startsAt": "2018-06-01T23:13:46+00:00",
         "endsAt" : "2018-06-30T00:01:00+00:00",
         "value" : 4
      },
      { 
         "startsAt": "2018-07-01T23:13:46+00:00",
         "endsAt" : "2018-07-30T00:01:00+00:00",
         "value" : 10
      }  
   ]
}
```

I'm looking to be able to, within elasticsearch, be able to pull the max value of the children whose timespans include right now, and use the default as a backup. The reason I want to do it within elasticsearch is so that I can sort on it.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by pull to parent? You want create a new field in parent doc or replace the defaultValue field's value with Max value?

Comment: @sramalingam24 Either one would be totally okay with me.

Comment: Let me take a step back actually, getting the value isn't the hard part. Sorting is the hard part. I know I can do a sort on an aggregation of nested values with a filter, but that doesn't allow for a default fallback I don't believe.

Comment: Well if you update the the parent doc then there is reverse nested aggregation which you probably could use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html

Comment: Thanks for the help but I've decided I'm just going to process it between elasticsearch and returning it to the client.